# RN UI component library based on existing native library

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin, mobile, cross-platform

we're trying to export existing UI library written in Kotlin into RN. Obviously there are methods such as described in RN docs to createNewInstance, create manager, specify ReactProps and e.g onPress events, create package, export it from native's end and import from RN's end. It works fine when you need to create one unique type of component.

But what about having the whole UI library? Instead of View - ImportedView, Button => ImportedButton etc. Ideally would be to overwrite functionality such as handling events etc, and take only styles from native's end. I may be not very precise, RN is new to me.